# ruby glade/gtkbuilder example?

Tags: ruby, gtk, glade, gtkbuilder

I was using ruby and glade2 to design the user interface for a while in the new version of glade3 i can use gtkbuilder format to generated xml file instead of libglade.

is there any example? i searched google but i had no luck!

Answer (score 6):

It's really simple: just create your GUI with Glade (and save it as GtkBuilder) and then use it in ruby with:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gtk2'
# require 'libglade2' #you don't need this anymore

builder = Gtk::Builder.new
builder.add_from_file(file)
builder.connect_signals {|handler| method(handler) }
```

the first line creates the Builder object, which is responsible of creating the `Glib::Objects` from your xml definition and also stores them for later use (you can call `get_object(objname)` on builder, it will return the widget defined with `objname`).

The second line actually loads your interface definition, where `file` is the path to your gtkbuilder file.

The third line is somewhat more obscure. `connect_signals` calls the block provided once for every signal you have defined in your interface. `handler` is just a string (the name of the signal). You are supposed to return a proc (or anything invokable with `call`) from the block: that block will be invoked everytime the signal defined by `handler` is fired. In this example the block is just returning a method with the same name as the signal (and, for simplicity's sake, it is assumed that there is a method for every one of the signals defined in the interface).

Answer (score 3):

You're right on the lack of pre-written tutorials, but the usage of gtkbuilder in Ruby is almost identical to Python (same function names, call orders) so these might be of interest -

GTK::Builder module: http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3ABuilder

Python code:

```
import sys
import gtk

class TutorialTextEditor:

    def on_window_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):

        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("tutorial.xml") 

        self.window = builder.get_object("window")
        builder.connect_signals(self)       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    editor = TutorialTextEditor()
    editor.window.show()
    gtk.main()
```

Source: http://www.micahcarrick.com/01-01-2008/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-3.html

Answer (score 3):

Another working version, in object oriented form:

```
require 'gtk2'

class Builder < Gtk::Builder

def initialize xml
        super()

        self.add_from_string(xml)

    self['main'].set_window_position Gtk::Window::POS_CENTER
        self['main'].signal_connect('destroy') { Gtk.main_quit }
        self['main'].show_all

    self.connect_signals{ |handler| method(handler) }

end

def on_button_clicked w

    case w.label
            when 'quit'
                Gtk::main_quit
            else
                puts "# on_button_clicked : " + w.label

    end
    end

def on_main_destroy
        puts "# on_main_destroy"
        Gtk::main_quit
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $0

xml = <<EOI
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
       <object class="GtkButton" id="quit">
        <property name="label">quit</property>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
EOI


    Gtk.init
        builder = Builder.new(xml)
    Gtk.main

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same really. Here is a glade example: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5251 substitute with the proper methods and you're set.

There is an IDE written in Ruby: http://github.com/danlucraft/redcar/tree/master but I wasn't able to find it's main file to begin with to see if it uses builder.

Comment: Redcar is implemented on top of JRuby/SWT, so not at all GTK related.

Comment: That's because they switched. At the time of writing my comment, it was relevant.